# Renaming the elements of a mathematical structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

One of the most basic insights about mathematical structures is that we can rename their elements without fundamentally changing the structure.

**Question.** How do we actually formalize this observation in its maximum generality?

---

Here's an attempt I made, taking topological spaces as an example.

**Claim:** Suppose $X$ and $X'$ are sets and $f : X \rightarrow X'$ is a bijection. Then for all topological spaces $(X,\tau),$ there exists a **unique** topological space $(X',\tau')$ such that $f$ is a homeomorphism $(X,\tau) \rightarrow (X',\tau').$

*Proof sketch*.

Existence: Just take $\tau' = \{\;f(B) \mid B \in \tau\;\}.$

Uniqueness: Suppose we have distinct $\tau',\tau''$ satisfying the condition. Then: $$B \in \tau' \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(B) \in \tau \Leftrightarrow f(f^{-1}(B)) \in \tau''$$

So $\tau'=\tau'',$ a contradiction.

*Remark*. I wasn't sure how to tag the question. Please feel free to edit.

Comment: Isomorphism... roughly 'same shape'.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy ahaha yes I know that much :-)

Comment: Does that not answer your question?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy, I don't know. In category theory, an isomorphism is just a morphism with both a left and a right inverse. What definition of isomorphism were you thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called *[transport of structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure)*. Formally, take two sets $X,Y$ with a bijection $f \colon X \to Y$. Suppose that $X$ is the base set of a $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathfrak X$. Then there exist a $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathfrak Y$ with $Y$ as base set defined by : for every constant symbol $c$, function symbol $\phi$ and relation symbol $R$ of the language $\mathcal L$,
$$c^{\mathfrak Y} := f(c^{\mathfrak X}),$$
$$\phi^{\mathfrak Y} := (y_1,\dots,y_k) \mapsto f(\phi^{\mathfrak X}(f^{-1}(y_1),\dots,f^{-1}(y_k))),$$
$$R^{\mathfrak Y} := \{ (y_1,\dots,y_k) \in Y^k : (f^{-1}(y_1),\dots,f^{-1}(y_k)) \in R^{\mathfrak X}\}.$$

Moreover, this structure makes $f$ an isomorphism of $\mathcal L$-structures. By definition of "isomorphism of $\mathcal L$-structures", it is unique.

Comment: The more common term, to my knowledge, is *transport of structure*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that is the term indeed, I couldn't remember it. Thanks, I edit.

Comment: Note that this process works not only for algebraic structures like in your first order formulation but in more general "structures on a set", like the one (a topology) given as an example by the OP.