# Making $[0,2\pi)$ homeomorphic to $S^1$, circle in a plane

Tags: general-topology

I have read that $[0,2\pi)$ and $S^1$ can't be homeomorphic or that $[0,2\pi)$ can't be compact. However I think that is the case with subspace topoloogy on $[0,2\pi)$. If we change the topology on $[0,2\pi)$ a little, then both the above statements become true. Consider the topology on $[0,2\pi)$ generated by the following base:
$$\mathcal{B} := \{I \subset [0,2\pi)| I = (a,b), \
                                      0 \leq a < b \leq 2\pi\
                                      \vee [0,a) \cup (b,2\pi),\
                                      0 < a < b < 2\pi\}$$

Topology on $S^1$ by the subspace topology in complex plane.
Then the map
$$t \to e^{it}$$

is a homeomorphism between $[0,2\pi)$ and $S^1$. Am I correct. Point me in the right direction.

Comment: Give the argument that $\mathcal{B}$ gives a topology and then that $t \mapsto e^{it}$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: It looks like your supposed basis $\mathcal{B}$ contains sets that are **already** open in $[0,2\pi)$ in its usual topology, so how is this topology different from the usual one?

Comment: @Randall because it doesn't contain **all** open subsets of the Euclidean topology. In particular $[0,a)$ is not open in the new topology (even though it is open in the Euclidean). Here open neighbourhoods of $0$ have to contain $(b,2\pi)$ interval as well. So now you can actually approach $0$ by going towards $2\pi$. And yes, with this topology I'm pretty sure this space is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Ah, I see.......

Comment: It is not that «$[0,2\pi)$ cannot be compact»: it simply isn't.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez that depends on the topology, doesn't it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The new topology contains standard neighbourhoods of $x\in(0,2\pi)$ but for $x=0$, its neighbourhoods are of the form $[0,a)\cup (b,2\pi)$ and so it kind of wraps around the interval. Meaning now we can approach $0$ by going towards $2\pi$. Sounds like a circle, indeed.

So, in order to prove that $f:t\mapsto e^{it}$ is a homeomorphism you only need to prove two things: that it is continuous and that the new topology is compact. Because we already know that $f$ is bijective. I'm not going to show it holds for this particular $f$, although I do believe it works.

I can provide you with a different argument that this new $C=[0,2\pi)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$. Consider the standard (closed) Euclidean interval $I=[0,2\pi]$ and

$$g:I\to C$$
$$g(t)=\begin{cases}
t &\text{if }t\neq 2\pi \\
0 &\text{for }t=2\pi
\end{cases}$$

It is not hard to see that this is a continuous map (consider preimages of open subsets from $\mathcal{B}$). Since $I$ is compact then this is a quotient map ($C$ is easily seen to be Hausdorff btw). And thus $C$ is homeomorphic to the quotient $[0,2\pi]/\{0,2\pi\}$, which is well known to be homeomorphic to $S^1$ (we are just glueing two ends of an interval).

Well, with this argument you at least know for sure that $C$ is compact. And therefore you would only need to show that $f:t\mapsto e^{it}$ is continuous. Moreover, if we look at how preimages of arcs in $S^1$ through $f$ look like, it becomes clear that this new topology is obtained simply by transfering topology from $S^1$ to $[0,2\pi)$ through (the inverse of) $f$.

Comment: We are not supposed to answer (multi-)duplicates (I proposed one of them in the comments above, 1 hour before you answered). Moreover, [the generic answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4588308/386889) is much simpler and, imo, more instructive.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't remember ever agreeing to not answer a question for whatever reason. Moreover, whatever you perceive as simpler and/or more instructive is totally your opinion. Not to mention that this linked answer doesn't even address OP's question directly.

Comment: I never said you agreed, I just recalled the rules on MSE. Unfortunately, we have to submit or quit. Haven't you ever been called to order by moderators on this subject? I have, including the mention of what they call "abstract duplicates" (i.e. general posts and answers which may serve as duplicates for particular cases). This one is a perfect example.

Comment: @AnneBauval I haven't been called to order by moderators, sorry to disappoint you. This answer is not a duplicate. It may be an alternative, but definitely not a duplicate. I don't know which rule prohibits my answer. And even if there is such rule, I'll be honest with you: I really don't care. I'm here to help people, not to argue about rules. I strongly believe that the culture of "follow rule to the letter" is toxic, especially here at SE, where people get bullied for questions they ask. I'm not going to be part of that. Even if moderators close this answer, it won't change my attitude.

Comment: And unfortunately for you - I won't neither submit nor quit. Your problem is not my problem.

Comment: Making the connection between the proposed "abstract duplicate" and this question more or less is impossible to anyone who has to ask this question. Marking this as a duplicate to that is something that only makes sense if you already know the answer to this question...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Offering duplicates to a questionner (who was obviously not aware of them) teaches the OP what they needed to know, in the same way as a direct answer would: the OP was of course not aware [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4671770/386889) but it is redundant with the duplicates, which are not more "abstract" than needed by the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know we should not answer your question here (since it has at least two duplicates: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588135), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476464)) but you seem to need it, so I edit this as a "community wiki" post.

Yes you are correct, and you  were already in "the right direction". No neeed of compactness or any other sophisticated and specific arguments. [Keep it simple and *be lazy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

What you did is called a [*transport of structure*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure). This is a general way to equip a set with the same kind of structure as a given equinumerous set already equipped, using a bijection which then becomes *ipso facto* an isomorphism, without need of any further effort.

For example here, consider:

- *any set* $E$ [equipotent to $S^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) ($E$ can be your interval $[0,2\pi)$ but could as well be e.g. $\Bbb R$ or $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$),
- *any bijection* $f:E\to S^1,$ and
- *any basis* $\mathcal B_0$ of the usual topology $\tau_0$ of $S^1$,
  and define (exactly as you did!)
  $$\mathcal B:=\{f^{-1}(U)\mid U\in\mathcal B_0\}.$$

Then, *automatically and obviously*, $\mathcal B$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $E$ and $f$ is a homeomorphism from $(E,\tau)$ to $(S^1,\tau_0).$